# Find the source of athena query result

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, presto

We have thousands of files stored in S3. These files are exposed to athena so that we can query on them. While doing debugging i found that athena shows multiple blank lines when queries on a specific `id`. Given that there are thousands of files, I am not sure where that data is coming from.

Is there a way that i can see the source file for respective rows in athena result?

Comment: try `select *, "$path" from your_table where ...`. This works in Presto, so should work in Athena too.

Comment: awesome. please share this as an answer so that i can accept it.

Comment: are there any more fuctions like this? I was looking up at presto documentaiton and couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html#r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE_usage-pseudocolumns

Comment: @Patrick this is a link to Redshift docs. The question is about Athena.

Comment: It comes from this discussion https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=252484

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a hidden column exposed by Presto Hive connector: `"$path"`
This column exposes the path of the file particular row has been read from.

Note: the column name is actually `$path`, but you need to `"`-quote it in SQL. This is because `$` is otherwise illegal in an identifier.